# converting Get Thumbnail API to base64 with PowerShell (from Microsoft Computer Vision Get Thumbnail API)

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, tobase64string, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to get an thumbnail image from the Microsoft Computer Vision Get Thumbnail API and save the response as a base64 encoded string that can be used in an html img tag like so:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,...base64string..."></img>
```

If I start from a test.jpeg image I have on my local drive, I am able to generate a usable base64string:

```
[convert]::ToBase64String((get-content 'c:\test\test.jpeg' -encoding byte)) >> b64str.txt
```

When I try with data returned from the REST API I don't get get a usable base64string (I *do get a string* but it is not *usable* in the html img tag):

```
$acs_req_headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$acs_req_headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "...subscriptionkey...")
$acs_req_body = '{"url":"https://...url.../test/test.jpg"}'
                
[convert]::ToBase64String(([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((Invoke-RestMethod 'https://...url...cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/generateThumbnail?width=100&height=100&smartCropping=true&model-version=latest' -Method 'POST' -Headers $acs_req_headers -Body $acs_req_body -ContentType 'application/json')))) >> b64str.txt
```

I've been working on this for some days, and the above is as close as I have gotten to a string that *looks* close. The issue seems to be the format returned from the API service and the subsequent conversion to bytes and then base64string but I'm lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` is used to make HTTP request and translate the JSON response into objects. That's not what you want to do though. In that case use `Invoke-WebMethod` which *doesn't* convert the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get an image from google images with `Invoke-RestRequest` and I didn't manage to convert it to a valid base64 string.

But, with `Invoke-WebRequest` I managed to do so because the content is already in byte format:

```
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri 'https://static.remove.bg/remove-bg-web/8fb1a6ef22fefc0b0866661b4c9b922515be4ae9/assets/start_remove-c851bdf8d3127a24e2d137a55b1b427378cd17385b01aec6e59d5d4b5f39d2ec.png'

$b64str = [convert]::ToBase64String($req.Content)
```

I saw from [here](https://blog.truesec.com/2020/07/29/invoke-webrequest-vs-invoke-restmethod/) that `RestRequest` does some conversion under the hood? Maybe that's what causing the issues.

Give `Invoke-WebRequest` a shot. But don't use it as `Invoke-RestRequest` because it returns a `WebResponseObject` object which contains a `Content` property where your actual response will be.

Comment: Not just "some conversion". The method's help text explains its job is to make HTTP requests and parse the JSON response into an object.